# Chatbot using Microsoft Speech Recognition decision tree

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, chatbot

Chatbot is a very large subject in many language that can be solved using

- AIML chat engine (or same)
- Natural Language Processor
- ...

I'd like to know if it would work using Microsoft Speech Recognition Grammar ? It seems Microsoft use a Decision Tree to sort it's Grammar elements.

So filling a big list of sentences with holes <ruleref garbage> should works ?

EDIT:

- Is there real life chatterbot based on Microsoft Grammar & Speech Recognition ?

  - May be combined with a Markov chain for answers ?
- Is there a limit on sentences the engine can handle ?
- Is there limits on grammar decision tree in SDK 1.8 (Kinect)

Comment: Yes, it should work. Probably you want to clarify your question to make it more focused on a problem.

Comment: Well if it works i'm looking for a real exemple using Microsoft Grammar to create a chatter bot.

Comment: Which engine?  Microsoft.Speech.Recognition or System.Speech.Recognition?

Comment: I use Microsoft.Speech

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *could*, but you would have to take advantage of many MS-internal undocumented features (e.g., the decision tree lattices, just for starters).

That being said, however, a long time ago, in a previous position, I wrote a version of Eliza based on a dictation recognition engine.  It didn't take advantage of any special features of the SR engine, though; just textual pattern matching.  So you could just feed the SR recognition directly into AIML.  It's probably better than you expect.

Comment: As I understand you only perform Speech2Text then give text to Eliza "like" ? That's an option but I think Microsoft Grammar provides very good recognition. Did someone code an AIML to Grammar ?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeEncausse The problem, as always, is that Microsoft.Speech.Recognition has better accuracy at the cost of supporting natural language (i.e., dictation).  AIML (and other chatbots) presume natural language input, which more or less goes against the design principles of the Microsoft.Speech.Recognition engine.

Comment: I agree, I thought because of decision tree it would be possible to mimic behavior of AIML without performance lost